# How can I detect when the device gets a new IP?

Tags: android, ip, dhcp

For multicast purposes, I'm looking for a simple way to detect when the IP of an Android device changes. How can I go about doing so?

More specifically, I'm looking to detect:

- When the device connects to a new Wifi network and it gets an IP from the DHCP
- When the device for some reason needs to renew an IP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with the [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html):

You can use this to query the current connection state:

```
ConnectivityManager connMananger = (ConnectivityManager) 
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo netInfo = connMananger.getActiveNetworkInfo();
```

The current IP address of network interfaces can be acquired with [NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getNetworkInterfaces%28%29)

And you can receive automatic notification of when the connection state changes via the [CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)

Comment: Sounds good. But does that broadcast only happen when an IP changes, or can lots of different things trigger it?

Comment: It can be triggered by any change in connectivity, but I believe there should be some extras to check, or you can detect the differences between NetworkInfo/NetworkInterface objects

Comment: CONNECTIVITY_ACTION: "This constant was deprecated in API level 28."